# Graphileon InterActor Settings Page not rendering properly on first startup

Tags: neo4j, graphileon

I am trying to get InterActor Community Edition running on my ubuntu 16.04 machine by following the instructions on this page
  `http://docs.graphileon.com/interactor/Getting_started/Setup_InterActor/Installation.html`

I am fine up to the point I do the `docker run...`-command.

Also, I have neo4j CE 3.2.5 already running at that time....

When I open the Startpage `http://localhost:8000` it shows following
[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dJq8.png)

Contrary to the description no settings page is shown.

I also opened it directly by typing `localhost:8000/settings` in the browser and I got the [settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqzvw.png) obviously with missing form-inputs and no styles rendered (compared to picture on installation instruction page)

I thought files were missing, therefore did a `docker exec -it interactor /bin/bash` to check sources (especially js an css-files) within  the running container under the directory `/var/www/html/interactor/`, seemed to be ok, but i do not know how the permissions have to be set, so here they are in the runing container:

```
root@ffb64b944023:/var/www/html/interactor# ll
total 168
drwxr-xr-x 21 www-data www-data  4096 Oct  2 18:32 ./
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root      4096 Oct  2 18:32 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   446 Sep  6 14:26 .htaccess
-rw-r-----  1 www-data www-data 90804 Sep  6 14:26 INTERACTOR_END_USER_LICENSE_AGREEMENT.pdf
drwxr-x---  4 www-data www-data  4096 Sep  6 14:27 css/
drwxr-x---  4 www-data www-data  4096 Sep  6 14:27 dashboard/
-rw-r-----  1 www-data www-data  5430 Jun 21 15:19 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  5738 Sep  6 14:26 favicon.png
drwxr-x---  2 www-data www-data  4096 Sep  6 14:27 images/
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  6929 Sep  6 14:26 index.php
drwxr-x---  4 www-data www-data  4096 Sep  6 14:27 js/
drwxr-x---  3 www-data www-data  4096 Oct  1 19:31 persistent/
drwxr-x--- 14 www-data www-data  4096 Sep  6 14:27 php/
drwxr-x---  2 www-data www-data  4096 Sep  6 14:27 scripts/
drwxr-x--- 11 www-data www-data  4096 Oct  2 18:32 settings/
drwxr-x---  2 www-data www-data  4096 Sep  6 14:27 templates/
-rw-r-----  1 www-data www-data    98 Sep  6 14:26 version.json
```

thus I tried to open the linked sources in the pagesource within the browser and got some of the files opened and some not, due to 403-Error.

I wonder if the provided image is somehow misconfigured regarding the permissions or if I am doing something wrong.

The strange thing is that I already had it running after I clicked all of the linked sources in the pagesource and reloaded the settings page.

When I finished playing around in interactor I used a `docker stop interactor`. neither a `docker start interactor` nor a `docker restart interactor` gave me a working interactor-instance back and I cannot get it working anymore...what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue but so far i cannot find a permanent solution.

The only thing to make it work is to connect to the container:

`sudo docker exec -i -t interactor /bin/bash`

And the run:

`chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/interactor -R`

even if all the files are already set like that.

You have to do this everytime you start the container.

We are working on a fix for this.

Disclaimer: i am a developer for Graphileon.

Comment: hi alex, thx for the reply. i also noticed to login with the neo4j credentials first in order to get to the settings page, which i was not aware of so far, but i will double check this :)

Comment: also i think `docker restart interactor` does not seem to work. if i do so, the existing container seems to start up and exit immediately.  at the moment my i work with `docker run -t -d -p 8000:80 --name interactor -v interactor:/persistent/ graphileon/interactor-community` then `docker exec -it  interactor /bin/bash` to attach to container and change permissions like you described above. when i am finished i use `docker stop interactor` and `docker rm interactor` and when i want to play again with interactor i am starting again with `docker run -t -d...`.

Comment: another point is, that after stopping the container apache2 is still running. and interestingly a `docker logs interactor` gives me this message `docker logs interactor AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`. can't say if this is a problem for `docker restart...`...?

Comment: The issues seem to be deeper. Until we manage to fix them you can try out the online sandbox of InterActor: https://interactor.graphileon.com/sandbox/signup.html.